# MySQL and node.js error

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to conect to mysql database but get error:

> bash-4.2# node node.js { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]   code:
>   'ECONNREFUSED',   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',   syscall: 'connect',
>   fatal: true }

Here is code for serever:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");

// First you need to create a connection to the db
var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "root",
  password: ""
});

con.connect(function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  console.log('Connection established');
});

con.end(function(err) {
  // The connection is terminated gracefully
  // Ensures all previously enqueued queries are still
  // before sending a COM_QUIT packet to the MySQL server.
});
```

Any idea what couse error?

Comment: Your username is an empty string?

Comment: No my pass is empty string, i found soulution if I allow outside connection in mysql config file it will establish conn, any other way to connect to mysql?

Comment: Perhaps your `my.cnf` is set to skip (TCP) networking and only allow connections on the UNIX socket?

Comment: Try changing your host name to 127.0.0.1.  That is the default mysql bind-ip address